# Inverting colors within shape in Processing

Tags: processing, p5.js

I want to draw shapes which invert the color of the pixels underneath them.

[image]

I know similar effects can be achieved in black and white using by setting the `blendMode()` to `DIFFERENCE`. However this does not work for colours.

I have also tried to use `filter(INVERT)` but this affects the whole canvas rather than specific areas.

Is there any way to efficiently achieve these aims in Processing, hopefully with built-in functionality?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not seeing why blendMode does not work for this:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  noStroke();
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  translate(width / 2, height / 2);

  push();
  fill(0, 255, 0);
  rect(0, 0, width * 0.6, height * 0.6);
  pop();

  push();
  blendMode(DIFFERENCE);
  fill(255);
  ellipse(width * 0.3, height * 0.3, 100, 100);
  pop();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could probably do:

```java
color col = get(x, y);
color colInv = color(255 - col.r, 255 - col.g, 255 - col.b, 255 - col.a);
```

Not sure if you can do `255 - col` all at once. Also I'm not sure if this would actually work, but it should...

Also `get(x, y)` takes a while, so you can also do it with the pixel array `The coding train` has a nice video on the pixel array.

Comment: While this answer is technically correct, the part where the OP doesn't know how to limit the color change to a specific zone isn't answered and would be a great improvement if you have time to commit to this answer.

Comment: Well, you can just put the color in `fill()` or if you want you can multi-sample but that will be very hard, at that point I believe you'd have to draw the shapes yourself too, processing might have it though, not completely sure.